# How to get object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

guys!
i'm at a dead end(

I have an array of objects:

```
[{"All": "all"}, {"Success": "successCompleted"}, {"Refund": "refunded"}, {"Error": "error"}]
```

So, I need to get this from that array:

```
{All: "all", Success: "successCompleted, Refund: "refunded", Error: "error"}
```

But I can't find any pretty solution (

Please help someone!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = [{"All": "all"}, {"Success": "successCompleted"}, {"Refund": "refunded"}, {"Error": "error"}]

const output = input.reduce((final, obj) => ({ ...final, ...obj }))

console.log(output)
```